# Nuxt 3: Do you need SSR for /server routes?

Tags: nuxt3

I'm learning Nuxt3. I want to be able to specify API routes with JSON responses in the `server/` directory. When building the site, do I need to have SSR enabled in order to "ping" API routes?

Comment: It's not common, guys. Try to change your design or customize 'routes' in `app.vue`

Comment: I have a Nuxt 3 site where I want to retrieve some simple information from API without the need of implementing in in say Laravel. I know that Nuxt 3 provides server api routes, but the question is when I build the project for production, do I need SSR to handle those api routes.

Comment: @zoltalar, you don't need SSR (Server-Side Rendering) while handling those API routes.